# Assigning ports of an n bit multiplexer

Tags: vhdl, multiplexer, port

I have ONE n-to-1 multiplexer and I'm trying to assign its n input ports from another component which has n output ports. How can I do this?

My code is given  below, and the errors. 
I've ommitted the other component to avoid confusion.

Errors:

1. Unknown identifier "i".
2. Individually associated formal "mux_in" must be identified with a locally static name.
3. Actual (indexed name) for formal "mux_in" is not a static signal name.

Code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

package data_array is
CONSTANT Block_Size      : integer := 64; 
CONSTANT Entry_length  : integer := 32;  
type signal_array is array(Block_Size downto 0) of std_logic_vector (Entry_length-1 downto 0);
end package data_array;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library work;
USE work.data_array.all; --including the package

entity A is

generic (
  Block_Size    : integer := 64; 
  Entry_length  : integer := 32   
  );


  port(
    sel:            in integer;
    new_entry:      in std_logic_vector(Entry_length-1 downto 0); 
    clk:            in std_logic;          
    reset:          in std_logic;          
    done:           out std_logic;                             --indicates completion of shifting
    last_entry:     out std_logic_vector(Entry_length-1 downto 0)
   );

end A;



architecture Synchronous of A is


    Component Multiplexer 

      generic (
        Block_Size    : integer := 64; 
        Entry_length  : integer := 32   
        );

      port(
        sel:        in integer;
        mux_in:     in signal_array;
        Mux_out:    out std_logic_vector(Entry_length-1 downto 0)
         );

    end component;

  --Intermediate signals

   signal interconnect : signal_array;
   signal temp_entry : std_logic_vector(Entry_length-1 downto 0);

  begin 

  temp_entry <= new_entry;

      --Instantiating the mux     
           mux: Multiplexer
                generic map(
                  Block_Size     => Block_Size,
                  Entry_length => Entry_length 
                  )

                port map(
                  sel        => sel,
                  mux_in(i)  => interconnect(i),
                  Mux_out    => temp_entry 
                   );

 end Synchronous;
```

Answer (score 3):

The first error

> Unknown identifier "i".

gives a very good clue as to the issue. `i` *isn't* defined.

There isn't a need to "index" the array, which is what I assume you're trying to do, since both types are the same:

```
mux_in:     in signal_array;
...
signal interconnect : signal_array;
```

All you need to do is this:

```
mux_in  => interconnect,
```

And that would deal with #1, as far as I can see. I don't know if #2 and #3 are additional issues, sometimes multiple errors are caused by one problem.

If this still doesn't fix #2 and #3, post the rest of the code (the mux and package), and I'll recreate the issue on my side and poke around a bit further :)

Comment: +1. It should solve (2) and (3) since "interconnect" is a locally static name (which means, static : its meaning can be determined before runtime, unlike interconnect(i), and locally : you don't need to elaborate the rest of the design to find it)

Comment: yes removing the i worked. thanks!
actually, earlier my interconnect and mux_in had been declared differently. interconnect was (0 to Block size) and mux_in was (Block_size down to 0). I guess due to this error it wasn't allowing me to assign mux_in <= interconnect. Hence I was trying mux_in(i) <= interconnect (i). While posting here, I changed both to the same type, but forgot to remove the i and recompile!